# Is there any way to view the internal mount point of a samba cifs from windows?

Tags: samba, cifs

Example:

To be accesed from windows, I have a samba cIFs called \data\cnd\video it points to this path of the server: 10.50.2.80/vol/conten_delivery_network/videos  is the any way to view this path from windows??

thanks in advide!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to see from a client which is the local path of a shared folder on the server.

If the server shares out `\\ServerName\Share`, you can't tell if that's actually stored on the server in `D:\Data\Something` or `E:\OtherData\SomethingElse\Share`, or anywhere else. This is just not supported by the SMB protocol, and it's always true, regardless of the server or the client being Windows or Samba.

Comment: i supose that.. But there always a small hope :D thanks!!